# Selenium set Firefox Profile not showing print popup

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like to set the preferences of the Firefox Profile to not opening printing dialog when I click on JavaScript events like this:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Print this page</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    window.print();
}
</script>
```

I tried this so far on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine, but it hasn't worked:

```
profile.setPreference("capability.policy.blockPrinting.Window.print", "noAccess");
profile.setPreference("capability.policy.default.Window.print","noAccess");
```

Comment: Note that your solution using "capability.policy.*" _used_ to work in older Firefox versions. It no longer works, however. I think it was removed in Firefox 29 - see [the note on 'Per-domain Configurable Security Policies'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/29/Site_Compatibility) in the compatibility notes.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318172/work-around-for-selenium2-print-popup#answer-8457797), they got around it by enabling

```
"print.always_print_silent": "true",
"print.show_print_progress": "false"
```

Try putting that in your preference:

```
profile.setPreference("print.always_print_silent", "true");
profile.setPreference("print.show_print_progress", "false");
```

Be careful though, that *might* actually execute a print and physically print paper if it's hooked up, potentially.

Answer (score 0):

The right solution for using with selenium is:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("print.always_print_silent", true);
profile.setPreference("print.show_print_progress", false);
```

true and false must be boolean and not string!